# Overrite custom extension's tab form in admin

Tags: overrides, grid, magento-1

[image]

I want add new option in tab form.For this I have tried to overrite that file but getting an error

Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /app/code/local/Test/Helloworld/Block/Adminhtml/Helloworld/Group/Edit/Tabs.php on line 19.

File I am overriding is : Test_Helloworld_Block_Adminhtml_Helloworld_Group_Edit_Tab_Main.

To override this file I am doing below code :

Config.xml

```
<blocks>         
    <helloworld>
        <rewrite>
            <adminhtml_helloworld_group_edit_tab_main>
                  Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Mymodule_Group_Edit_Tab_Main
            </adminhtml_helloworld_group_edit_tab_main>
        </rewrite>
    </helloworld>   
</blocks>
```

Create file :

```
app/code/local/Mynamespace/Mymodule/Block/Adminhtml/Mymodule/Group/Edit/Tab
```

Comment: You don't have a linefeed in your `adminhtml_helloworld_group_edit_tab_main` node, do you? That will break the system for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can add field to exciting form using **adminhtml_block_html_before** event

```
    <events>
      <adminhtml_block_html_before>
        <observers>
          <adminhtml_block_html_before_handler>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>modulename/observer</class>
            <method>addMyField</method>
            <args></args>
          </adminhtml_block_html_before_handler>
        </observers>
      </adminhtml_block_html_before>
    </events>
```

Observer.php code as below code add new field set.

```
public function addMyField(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {
                $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
                if (!isset($block)) {
                    return $this;
                }
                if ($block->getType() == 'slider/adminhtml_slider_edit_tab_form') {  
                    $form = $block->getForm();
                    //create new custom fieldset 'website'
                     $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('website_field', array(
                            'legend' => 'Website Extras',
                            'class' => 'fieldset-wide'
                        )
                    );
                    //add new website field
                    $fieldset->addField('website', 'text', array(
                        'name'      => 'website',
                        'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Website'),
                        'title'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Website'),
                        'disabled'  => false,
                    ));
                }
            }
```

below code for exciting fieldset

```
public function addMyField(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {
                $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
                if (!isset($block)) {
                    return $this;
                }
                if ($block->getType() == 'slider/adminhtml_slider_edit_tab_form') {  
                    $form = $block->getForm();
                    $fieldset = $form->getElement('my_form');   //your form field set instead of "my_form"  
                    $fieldset->addField('website', 'text', array(
                        'name'      => 'website',
                        'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Website'),
                        'title'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Website'),
                        'disabled'  => false,
                    ));
                }
            }
```

Hope it will helpful to you.

Comment: Working like charm!